# Make a required class properties not required

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, model-view-controller, validation

I have a class set up to hold values on a registration form (VB.NET, MVC), and among the properties is a Password property:

```
Public Class RegisterModel

    ...

    Private _password As String
    <DisplayName("Password:"), Required(), ValidatePasswordLength(), DataType(DataType.Password)> _
    Public Property Password() As String
        Get
            Return _password
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _password = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

This works great when registering a new user, but I'd like to use the same class to update existing users. (Note: this app is run by an admin who is in charge of registering individuals and assigning passwords.) The way I'd like it to behave is if the admin leaves the password blank, then the password is not changed, but the rest of the information is. If I use this class, the password can't be left blank because it fails on the Required() and ValidatePasswordLength() calls.

Is there a way to use this class but tell the model to ignore these particular validations? Even if I leave the password field off my edit form, it still fails. Do I need to create a whole duplicate class without these restrictions on the password field? There must be a better way.

Comment: I suggest on clientside when the update button is clicked, in javascript you give the textbox a random value (predefined which you check on server side in conjunction with if the entity already exists) to pass validation, and then on the server side you get the existing entities password and set the new entities password to the existing one? I am not saying this is the best/right way to do it though

Answer (score 2):

You could implement `IDataErrorInfo` and have a flag set on the model which indicates whether it is being used by an admin or not - you could then validate conditionally.

But overall, I'd say this is a bit of a code smell. You're using a model for two different, incompatible purposes. It'd be better to use a separate view model.

Comment: This is the quintessential reason to use ViewModels.

Comment: With a view model, aren't you now maintaining two models each time there's a model change? Is that the price for having the two views perform different functions?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) library.  It's a fantastic way to separate the concerns of your view (view model) and the actual validation you want to perform.  You could pass parameters into it to drive different behavior.  Check out [When/Unless](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Customising&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#WhenUnless) conditions or just writing completely custom validation methods with the [Must operator](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Validators&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#Predicate).

```
public class RegisterModelValidator: AbstractValidator<RegisterModel>
{
  public RegisterModelValidator(bool isAdmin) 
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Password).NotEmpty().Unless(isAdmin);
        ...
    }
}
```

As long as your view model would have identical properties in both scenarios, you should use the one view model and one validation class.  If the model varies at all I'd use two view models as David recommends.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 ways:

1: add the   [ValidateInput(false )] attribute to the action

or

2: Add a new property to the Register Model

```
public bool IsNewUser {get;}
```

3: Create a new class level attribute that takes IsNewUser into account when validating